# django post request data caching

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, http-post

hi have a template with a form and many inputs that pass some data trough a POST request to a view, that process them and send the result to another template. in the final template, if i use the browser back button to jump to the first view, i can see again old data. i refresh the page and i insert new data, i submit again but some old data remain when i see the  final view. the problem remain even if i restart the debug server. how can i prevent it? it seems that there's some data-caching that i can solve only flushing browser cache. this is the view code: http://dpaste.com/640956/ and the first template code: http://dpaste.com/640960/

any idea?

tnx - luke

Comment: What's all this `__contains__` stuff? You mean `if 'iono' in request.POST`. And you should use a Django form, anyway.

Comment: the problem remain: i've tried the danihp's solution: i create a folder 'util' inside my_app folder and i create a file NoCacheMiddleware.py with the posted code. then i've put in the setting.py middleware section the following string: 'my_app.util.NoCacheMiddleware.NoCacheMiddleware'. the server start, first page is loaded with no error, but even if i try to insert data in the first template and submit it, in the second one i have a mix of old and new data. i've also added pragma no cache meta tag in the html head in the base template, but neither this helped...i have no other ideas. any sugg

Answer (score 0):

Is not django who populate form. Is cache navigator. You should switch off cache navigator. I use a  custom middleware to do this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class NoCacheMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache must-revalidate proxy-revalidate no-store'
        return response
```

Remember to add middleware on settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'ghap.utils.middleware.NoCacheMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: tnx. is there a way to do it by with render_to_response? in any case how can i integrate your soultion in my case?

Comment: you should create a file called NoCacheMiddleware on some app. Copy NoCacheMiddleware class into this file and append the 'path' file to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on settyings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe autocomplete="off" in the form tag can help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion